# jquery does not show hidden div section with css

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, css-selectors, jquery-selectors

I'm using elementor to create a photo gallery that appears once the input button is clicked. My problem is that in the hidden div (css display:none) when I use show () or toggle () with jquery the gallery is not shown, but the other text elements do. They appear if I click in another link text. How is it possible? for the gallery I used a wordpress plugin called "Photoblock"(By inserting the shortcode in the div, the gallery show).

I leave my code here and here you can see what the page looks like [website](https://www.yayoservice.com/hair-makeup/)
just click on gallery to see the white section, and if you click on bio the photos will appear.

The html since I used elementor you can see it on the page with inspect

This is the css and the class of the div which hides all the elements

```
.apri{
 display:none;
 }
```

and this is the jquery with the button function that should bring up the div

```
var hbtn = $(".clicca");
var hcon = $(".apri");


hbtn.click(function(e) {
var index = hbtn.index(this) 
$(hcon).eq(index).slideToggle("slow");

e.preventDefault();     
});
```

thanks

Comment: A snippet makes only sense if there is something that can be executed and that shows the actual problem - which is obviously not the case here. Please add a real [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much show hide classes and also JS functions to complete a simple task. Don't know what is the CSS library you are using. But if you are using Bootstrap, this is so simple and that is my recommendation.

[Check Bootstrap Elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

You can simply use `.d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-none` to manage what you need here.

Comment: i'm not using bootstrap, and i see the problem here, is when i load a photo gallery it doesn't work, if i load single photos they show. I'm new to jquery, is there also any way to shorten the code? example with "this". Thank you